# WPF SplashScreen Creation and Control

Tags: xaml, screen-resolution

Create WPF Splashscreen to deal with all resolutions and sizes
Existing WPF Splashscreen too limited.  Cannot control duration or changes in monitor resolution and sizing.  Existing custom splashscreens creation too complex and limiting

**Thinking  outside the box**. ** XAML** is the solution.  5-10 lines of XAML code.
i have a very simplistic solution that is guaranteed to work, takes 5 minutes and is more flexible than any offered to date.  This resolves the issue of multiple resolutions and resizing
Specifically,

- add image to your image or assets folder
- make property as 'resource'
- go to bottom of your xaml design window - should be last entries inside the windows Grid
- add following lines
- In event handler simply make splashscreen visibility.hidden to display your main screen

Note: Added benefit - with this approach you can overlay textblocks/buttons and/or any information you like. example I have added 3 buttons at bottom of splashscreen for 'Copyrite', 'License' and 'Help'.  This is done by adding additional  tags.  placement is done through use of margin(n,n,n,n)

Thats it!!!